# Are XmlMtomReader and XmlMtomWriter fully implemented in Mono project?

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5, mono, xmlreader, xmlwriter

I'm working on a cross-platform solution currently. The solution uses **XmlMtomReader** and **XmlMtomWriter** from .NET framework 3.0.

Now i need to know if these two classes (and all the nessasary infrastructure around them) are fully supported in Mono project from the porting-it-to-linux point of view. :)

Comment: How about downloading the source and looking at it?

Comment: @John Saunders , what source do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it on the mono status:

http://go-mono.com/status/

You can also check your code using the mono migration analyser

http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA

I checked they are currently not implemented

Answer (score 1):

The APIs are available on the current Mono 2.6 preview, but they are not available on the 2.4 release (the current official release).